# I accidentally checked a "never send SMS" box on my phone, so now I can't find how to change that

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung, sms

So I can't send SMS messages on my Samsung On5...is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Settings -> Apps -> to the app which you used to send SMS -> Permissions -> SMS and Click the checkbox next to it

Answer (score 0):

go to Application Manager.

1. Scroll down to locate Messaging app and tap it.
2. Touch Clear Data.
3. Restart your device.
4. Try sending a text message. If it doesn't work perform a factory reset on your device.